# Using jquery to target data tags within json via ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I've got a simple ajax call returning some json which is working well however i'm struggling to select the elements with jquery afterwards. This this because of the way they are loaded with ajax?

At this stage all i'm trying to do is alert the contents of one of the data elements 'data-votes'

```
<div id="list-latest" class="pagelist"></div>
<script>
 $(function () 
  {
   $.ajax({                                      
     url: 'http://example.com/go.php',                  
     data: "",                        
     dataType: 'json',                  
     success: function(data)          
       {
         var $grouplist = $('#list-latest');
         $.each(data, function() {

           $('<div class="tile-item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alertme();" class="allinfo" data-votes="' + this.votes + '" data-views="' + this.Views '" >link</a></div>').appendTo($grouplist);

         });
       }

      });


    });
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function alertme(){
    alert($(this).attr("#data-votes"));
  }
</script>
```

Is it to do with how i'm trying to select (this) ?
At the moment it just returns 'undefined'

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the reference of `this` in the `alertme()` function is the `window`, not the element which raised the click event. You need to pass the reference as a parameter in the function. Also note the syntax to retrieve the `data` attribute is slightly off. Try this:

```
$('<div class="tile-item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alertme(this);" class="allinfo" data-votes="' + this.votes + '" data-views="' + this.Views '" >link</a></div>').appendTo($grouplist);
```

```js
function alertme(el){
   alert($(el).data("votes"));
}
```

It should be noted that it's much better practice to hook up your events using Javascript. In this case you'd need a delegated event handler as the elements in question are appended to the DOM dynamically after load. This method would mean that the `this` reference within the handler *would* refer to the element that raised the event. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'http://example.com/go.php',                  
        data: "",                        
        dataType: 'json',                  
        success: function(data) {
            var $grouplist = $('#list-latest');
            $.each(data, function() {
                $('<div class="tile-item"><a href="#" class="allinfo" data-votes="' + this.votes + '" data-views="' + this.Views '">link</a></div>').appendTo($grouplist);
            });
        });
    }

    $grouplist.on('click', '.allinfo', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).data("votes"));
    });
});
```